# How to make responsive Image and text displayed side by side in grid format

Tags: html, css

> Hi Expert,
>
> I want to display image and text in grid format.
>
> But the distance between the Image+text is big how can that be
> adjusted.
>
> Here is the codepen link
> https://codepen.io/melwyn-mendonca/pen/RwQPKbp

Attached is the image how it is displayed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwvpV.png)

Also want it in the middle of the page.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  
}
.grid-container>*{
  flex: 1;
  }

img{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.grid-item p{
  padding: 1rem;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="grid-item">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/podcast_063b8574-56e0-4fa2-a9a9-c85f701754f3.png?v=1651638533" alt="podcast"></div>
  <div class="grid-item-Text">
<p>Podcast</p>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/ebook.png?v=1651638533" alt="ebook"></div>
    <p>Ebooks</p>
    <div class="grid-item">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/youtube.png?v=1651638533" alt="youtube"></div>
<p>Youtube</p>
    </div>
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="grid-item">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/podcast_063b8574-56e0-4fa2-a9a9-c85f701754f3.png?v=1651638533" alt="podcast"></div>
  <div class="grid-item-Text">
<p>Podcast</p>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/ebook.png?v=1651638533" alt="ebook"></div>
    <p>Ebooks</p>
    <div class="grid-item">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/youtube.png?v=1651638533" alt="youtube"></div>
<p>Youtube</p>
    </div>
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="grid-item">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/podcast_063b8574-56e0-4fa2-a9a9-c85f701754f3.png?v=1651638533" alt="podcast"></div>
  <div class="grid-item-Text">
<p>Podcast</p>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/ebook.png?v=1651638533" alt="ebook"></div>
    <p>Ebooks</p>
    <div class="grid-item">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/youtube.png?v=1651638533" alt="youtube"></div>
<p>Youtube</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML (snippet):

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/podcast_063b8574-56e0-4fa2-a9a9-c85f701754f3.png?v=1651638533" alt="podcast">
      <p>Podcast</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/ebook.png?v=1651638533" alt="ebook">
      <p>Ebooks</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/youtube.png?v=1651638533" alt="youtube">
      <p>Youtube</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;  
}

.grid-item
{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item img{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.grid-item p {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ive have made a template for you hope it helps

```html
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Document</title>
                </head>
                
                <body>
                <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-cols-2 row-cols-lg-6 g-2 g-lg-3">
                <div class="col">
                <div class="p-md-2 ">
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/podcast_063b8574-56e0-4fa2-a9a9-c85f701754f3.png?v=1651638533" alt="podcast"    width="75%;" >
                
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <div class="p-2 ">use the name</div>
                </div>
                <div class="p-md-2 ">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/podcast_063b8574-56e0-4fa2-a9a9-c85f701754f3.png?v=1651638533" alt="podcast"    width="75%;" >
                
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <div class="p-2 ">use the name</div>
                </div>
                <div class="p-md-2 ">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/podcast_063b8574-56e0-4fa2-a9a9-c85f701754f3.png?v=1651638533" alt="podcast"    width="75%;" >
                
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <div class="p-2 ">use the name</div>
                </div>
                <div class="p-md-2 ">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/podcast_063b8574-56e0-4fa2-a9a9-c85f701754f3.png?v=1651638533" alt="podcast"    width="75%;" >
                
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <div class="p-2 ">use the name</div>
                </div>
                <div class="p-md-2 ">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0130/1797/2795/files/podcast_063b8574-56e0-4fa2-a9a9-c85f701754f3.png?v=1651638533" alt="podcast"    width="75%;" >
                
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                <div class="p-2 ">use the name</div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: How can it done by using HTML & CSS Flex